# Convert each row of a dataframe to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['aa', 'b', 'c']})
   A  B
0  1  aa
1  2  b
2  3  c
```

I want to convert each row of column `B` to a list. For example, my desired output is something like this:

```
   df_new
   A  B
0  1  [aa]
1  2  [b]
2  3  [c]
```

Comment: `df['B'].apply(lambda i: [i])`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to do stuff.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
print(df)
```

Comment: You could do it without ```apply``` also right? just ```df['B'] = df['B'].str.split()``` ?

Comment: Yes, you can also

Comment: I think that would be the best answer

Comment: @sophocles - Why do you think so?

Comment: for performance reasons. wouldn't it be better to not use ```apply``` when you can get the same result without the use of ```apply```?

Comment: @sophocles - yop, I wrongly understand `df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))` is used best here. But 100% agree `df['B'] = df['B'].str.split()` is better solution. It is a bit slowier, BUT if NaNs or number not failed like `df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))`

Answer (score 8):

I think solution from comments is very fast:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].map(lambda i: [i])
```

Faster is use list comprehension:

```
df['B'] = [[i] for i in df['B']]
```

---

**Performance**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['as', 'b', 'c']})

#30k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [93]: %timeit df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
11.1 ms ± 963 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [94]: %timeit df['B'].str.split()
13.1 ms ± 788 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


In [96]: %timeit df['B'].map(lambda i: [i])
7.15 ms ± 54.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [97]: %timeit df['B'].apply(lambda i: [i])
7.21 ms ± 48.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [98]: %timeit df['B'].str.split(',')
13.9 ms ± 1.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


In [99]: %timeit [[i] for i in df['B']]
5.84 ms ± 73.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `apply`:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(list)

   A    B
0  1  [a]
1  2  [b]
2  3  [c]
```

Comment: If one of the rows is something like `as`, it works wrong.

Comment: Could you add an example please?

Comment: change `a` to `as` get list `['a','s']`

Comment: Ok got it, yes. Would be good if the sample data above included that

Comment: @sophocles - yop, your solution working only if one letter, so not add to perfromance